# Просмотр исходного кода встроенных функций JS

Tags: javascript

Мне интересно, как работают некоторые встроенные функции в JavaScript, что у них внутри. Как я могу посмотреть их исходный код? Есть ли сайты, которые его описывают?
Не спецификацию, а уже готовый код js.

Comment: Возможно Вам поможет поисковик по исходникам хрома https://cs.chromium.org/

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/element.cc?q=getBoundingClientRect&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=1535

Comment: Проблема в том, что они написаны не на JS

Comment: Возникает вопрос - из чего должен состоять исходник встроенных функций, из других встроенных функций? Скорее всего они выполняются на бинарном (низком) уровне, т.  е., как текст их не прочитаешь. Для этого и требуется C#.